# Cuando quiero pasar el txtEdad.Text a ListarUsuario me lo marca como error por ser tipo int, como puedo solucionarlo para buscar por Edad en mi BD

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, datagridview

Estoy haciendo un programa Windows Form en C#, Visual Studio 2017, Framework 4.6.

El funcionamiento es para gestionar registros en una BD MySql y me da error para listar los registros en el dataGridView cuando quiero mostrar la edad, me dice que no se puede convertir string a int. Ya intenté con Convert.ToString de varias formas pero no funcionó, no sé como se arregla.

```
Listarusuario(conexion.conexion, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtEdad.Text);
```

EL txtEdad.Text DA ERROR DE: ARGUMENTO 5: NO SE PUEDE CONVERTIR DE 'STRING' A 'INT'

Por favor Ayuda!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Listarusuario(MySqlConnection conexion, string pNombre, string pApellido, string pEmail, int pEdad)
{            
    dgvUsuarios.DataSource = Clases.Usuario.BuscarYListarUsuario(conexion, pNombre, pApellido, pEmail, pEdad);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(conexion.AbrirConexion() == true)
        {
            Listarusuario(conexion.conexion, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtEdad.Text);
                conexion.CerrarConexion();
        }
    }
    catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
    
public class Usuario
{
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apellido { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int edad { get; set; }

    public Usuario() { }

    public Usuario(int pIdUsuario, string pNombre, string pApellido, string pEmail, int pEdad)
    {
        this.id_usuario = pIdUsuario;
        this.nombre = pNombre;
        this.apellido = pApellido;
        this.email = pEmail;
        this.edad = pEdad;
    }

    public static IList<Usuario> BuscarYListarUsuario(MySqlConnection conexion, string pNombre, string pApellido, string pEmail, int pEdad)
    {
        List<Usuario> Lista = new List<Usuario>();
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT id_usuario, nombre, apellido, email, edad FROM usuario WHERE nombre LIKE ('%{0}%') AND apellido LIKE ('%{1}%') AND email LIKE ('%{2}%') AND edad LIKE ('%{3}%')", pNombre, pApellido, pEmail, pEdad), conexion);
        MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
        
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Usuario pUsuario = new Usuario();
            pUsuario.id_usuario = reader.GetInt32(0);
            pUsuario.nombre = reader.GetString(1);
            pUsuario.apellido = reader.GetString(2);
            pUsuario.email = reader.GetString(3);               
            pUsuario.edad = reader.GetInt32(4);
            Lista.Add(pUsuario);
        }

        return Lista;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Mostra el error completo y la linea donde ocurre... si no, imposible ayudarte...

Comment: Y dd esta el codigo de tu metodo ListarUsuario

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad .text de un Control de form por defecto son string, tu necesitas convertirlo a Int, no a string. En este caso deberias hacer Convert.Toint32(txtedad.text). Espero que te sea útil, saludos

Comment: Gracias por intentar ayudarme, eso ya lo intente de varías formas pero el visual studio no me deja, me dice que no se puede hacer una conversión implícita de int a string o que no es válida.